# Silverlight and WCF with Windows Authentication

Tags: silverlight, wcf, authentication

I am writing a Silverlight client and a WCF Service library solution in an Intranet environment.

As I understand it, if I set up Windows Authentication then calls to the service methods will only succeed if the caller is Authenticated in Windows and I do not need to write code to provide user credentials. I have several questions around this.

1. Am I correct?
2. I have been asked to make my application time out (as is often done with Internet applications) making the user log in again. However, I have enabled 'Integrated Windows Authentication' in advanced IE options and 'Automatic logon only in Intranet Zone' in the Security section. Effectively, now the user does not login to my application but to IE and Silverlight passes these credentials automatically to the WCF Service. I can change to 'Prompt for username and password' but then the credentials are only lost when IE is closed which I cannot do on a timeout. Even if I could I would have to close all IE opened Windows that were participating in the Intranet zone as the authentication seems to be shared amongst them.
3. Is it possible to impersonate another user? I have seen code to do this from a Windows application but the intellisense when using Silverlight does not seem provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you use IIS Windows Authentification. WCF services can be confugured independently and they have security based on Windows identity too, but they are a bit more difficult than traditional approach.

Your questions:

1.To disable anonymous users and allow only those users who are authentificated in Windows, you can write the following code:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

After that user credentials will be required and passed automatically. And you don't need to send them from client's application.
If anonymous authentification is disabled by IIS, everything will work without extra code.

2.It's OK, IE and Chrome, unlike Firefox, don't require credentials every time when a user opens a web page. If you want to refresh a state of the application after timeout, you can do it without requesting credentials, for example using something of the sort of MessageBox.

3.Impersonation works only on a server side. But it's possibly to write necessary code in a WCF service and call it from a Silverlight client.

Comment: RE point 1, if I disable anonymous access then WCF tells me I must have anonymous access enabled even with Windows Authention.
RE point 2, how do you invalidate the credentials on timeout? The user is always logged in whilst IE is open so when time runs out what do you do?
RE point 3, I see what you mean, I hadn't thought of that, thanks.

Comment: @EzaBlade In the 2nd point I can't imagine a situation when credentials are changed after timeout and must be invalidated. But when I developped a wcf service with sessions, I used an extended proxy class that recreated channel after faults which were caused by timeouts. But probably I've confused wcf timeouts with other kinds of them. 1st point is strange because when I tried to use WCF Data Services, IIS permitted to use only one authentification exclusively.

Comment: Our penetration testing company wants the application to automatically log out basically after a set time of inactivity. As I cannot log out because the only way to do this is to close IE which I can't do via code, then I need to ivalidate the credentials so that further actions will prompt for them. As a side note you cannot use WCF Sessions in a Silverlight app.

Comment: @EzaBlade If a WCF service doesn't have sessions, there is no such concept as log in/out. But you can invalidate session in the asp.net application, there is the SessionState element in web.config, also you can call Session.Clear().